# organise change field values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, perl

i need to sort through a column in my database, this column is my category structure the data thats in the column is city names but not all the names are the same for each city, what i need to do is go through the values in the column i may have 20-40 value that are the same city but written differently i need a script that can interpret them  and change them to a single value

so i may have two values in the city column say:( england > london ) and ( westlondon ) but i need to change to just london, is there a script out there that is capable of interpreting the values that are already there and change them to the value  would want i know the dificult way of doing this one by one but wondered if there was a script in any language that could complete this

Comment: I think you're out of luck. About all you can do is use LIKE wildcards to find '%LONDON%', but there's no way to code something that figure out what is supposed to map to where, unless you figure it out in advance

Comment: Not too sure why someone downvoted you, I think it's a good question, so I put you back up to 0. Would be interesting to know if there's a program out there that can do this...

Comment: I think i may be out of luck with this one Ive searched everywhere thought someone would have come across this problem before i have over 16,000 category's that's not including the duplicates/variations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this sort of data clean-up plenty of times and I'm afraid I don't know of anything easier than just writing your own fixes.

One thing I can recommend is making the process repeatable. Have a replacement table with something like (rulenum, pattern, new_value). Then, work on a copy of the relevant bits of your table so you can just re-run the whole script.

Then, you can start with the obvious matches (just see what looks plausible) and move to more obscure ones. Eventually you'll have 50 without matches and you can just manually patch entries for this.

Making it repeatable is important because you'll be bound to find mis-matches in your first few attempts.

So, something like (syntax untested):

```
CREATE TABLE matches (rule_num int PRIMARY KEY, pattern text, new_value text)

CREATE TABLE cityfix AS 
SELECT id, city AS old_city, '' AS new_city, 0 AS match_num FROM locations;

UPDATE c SET c.new_city = m.new_value, c.match_num = m.rule_num 
FROM cityfix AS c JOIN matches m ON c.old_city LIKE m.pattern 
WHERE c.match_num = 0;

-- Review results, add new patterns to rule_num, repeat UPDATE
-- If you need to you can drop table cityfix and repeat it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: 16K is not so much. first use Perl's `DBI` (im assuming you are going to use Perl) to fetch that city column, store it in a hash (city name as the hash), then find your an algorithm that suites your needs (performance wise) to iterate over the hash keys and use `String::Diff` to find matching intersection (read about it, it definitely can help you out) and store it as a value.. then you can use that to update the database using the key (old value) and the value as the new value to update.